# how to load a large RGB image in python?

Tags: python, image, load

I am a beginner in Python. I would to load some tif images in Python and then do some image processing over them. At the starting point, I faced a problem of loading. the images have the size of (2000,2000,3) but Python just load up to 1920 on  rows and columns. I have copied my code for loading which is really simple and I expected that it would work but it did not. If anyone has suggestion for altering the code, I would be thankful for that.

```
infile2= 'e:/orthoData/test-PIL/a1.tif'
im2= Image.open (infile2)
im2.size
```

I know it is really simple but I have really stocked in this point.I tried to read about it in different Python documentation by was not successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Update - disregard previous answer (I completely misread the question)

The following should work fine. If it doesn't, the image is likely corrupted.

```
tif = Image.open('e:/orthoData/test-PIL/a1.tif')
```

Comment: thank you very much for your help. I would try and would inform u of the result.

Comment: @user2355306 - if it works, you can just click the check box next to my answer to mark it as the solution.

Comment: I have just realized that the code does not give a reliable result. well it reads the image with the size (2000,2000) and gives the output file with the size of (2000,2000) but when you open the tif file, you would observe that some parts of image are missing ,it seems to me that not whole the image is loaded. what do you recommend in this case?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Well, I tried your new guidance but still I have the same result. When I say show image, I would observe that about 80*80 pixels from upper and right side of the image is not shown though in the image size I see the right size which is 2000*2000. I open the image in another software and it is not corrupted. what do you think is the reason that it does not appear correctly?